# My default react app on windows OS wouldn’t work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

[image]

I am new in react-redux and coding in general and I am trying to learn.

So what I did:

- installing node js
- instaling npm i -g create-react-app
- uninstalling npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- install npx create-react-app my-app-name
- cd my-react-app-name
- npm start

my node version `node -v` v14.16.0

```
mian-react-app@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

‘Rudex\mian-react-app\node_modules.bin’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module ‘C:\Users\Ali Alghanay\Documents\Projects\source\repos\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js’
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: ‘MODULE_NOT_FOUND’,
requireStack:
```

```js
{
  "name": "mian-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a bit more information about the problem. Can you specify if you already installed all the dependencies by running `npm install` in the project folder and also share your node version by running the command `node --version` in your terminal and adding it to the question.  In addition it could be helpful to share the content of your `package.json` file.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood right, are you trying to create a basic React app by using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: added node --version & package.json \

Comment: yes exactly i am trying to create basic react app using `npx create-react-app app-name`!

Comment: I see that you have many other dependencies added to your `package.json`, which means that you were either installing other packages or using someone else code, which may be the answer to why you are having the issue. If you create a plain `create-react-app` without redux you should be able to run it right away by using `npm start`. Try to see if this helps: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9501#issuecomment-699177492

Comment: i don't think this is related to my problem but when i first try to install react i followed old tutorial which i used `npm install -global create-react-app@something-old` but i uninstall it anyway...  also in installing node js after the powershall opened i waited to long and i close it before it complete installing something i think it was "chocolatey" not sure but i reinstall it either

Comment: You could try to use yarn instead of npm. This was fixing our problem with multiple OS (mac and windows)

Comment: when i tried https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9501#issuecomment-699177492 i got > postinstall
> cd packages/react-error-overlay/ && yarn build:prod

Comment: 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ali Alghanay\Documents\Projects\source\repos\Scout website Project - React & Rudex\test\create-react-app-master
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c cd packages/react-error-overlay/ && yarn build:prod

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ali Alghanay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-04T17_45_31_334Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks for both of you guys @alexrogo @ross-u i solve it with help of mr.kevin Smith form freecodecamp community. 
the problem was whit my repo my `./` was full with spaces and the solution was simple removing the spaces from my repo!

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your answer and provide a link with the discussion in freecodecamp community, as a reference to the issue and how you went about solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `node_modules` folder.
Then run again:

```
$ npm install
```

Comment: please post your log if this is not working.

Comment: same thing nothing change

Comment: I added picture to my terminal may it helps